# How to implement browser history and bookmarks with jquery mobile and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a site with JQM, JQuery, PHP and MYSQL. The idea is to use ajax to pull information from the database (JSON) to insert it on the page. My only issue is that I am not sure how to implement the ajax in a way that makes it easy to bookmark pages and go back (to the last page) on the JQM site. I was thinking to use pushstate but am not sure on how to implement it. Can anyone point me to a tutorial on how to do this effectively or if they can put up some example code.

Comment: JQM handles all of this for you if you returned html rather than json, is there a specific reason you are trying to use json instead of html? Is the amount of data very large?

Comment: @KevinB it may eventually be but not at the moment however the data is dynamic based on choice so I assumed I have to use ajax and JSON

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the page url, so lets so your page URL is: test_page.php and json URL is test_json.php. You want to bookmark the page for all with the name "mark". So you bookmark test_page.php?name=mark. Then on page load you define it to your json to get all for mark.

This way you can bookmark the URL and just fetch according to the parameters in the URL.